# How to implement abstract Java class in Groovy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, groovy

I am trying to write some Spring code in Groovy from one of [Spring's tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/). When I write the following code in Groovy:

### Java

```java
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

### Groovy

```
@Component
class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = res as HttpServletResponse
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        chain.doFilter(req, res)
    }

    void init (FilterConfig filterConfig) {}
    void destroy() {}
}
```

I get the following error

```
Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'com.myproject.main.SimpleCORSFilter' must be declared abstract or the method 'void doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain)' must be implemented.
 @ line X, column Y.
   @Component
   ^
```

## Question

I have implemented the abstract `doFilter` method. Why is it not valid?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why can't you just declare SimpleCORSFilter as abstract?

Comment: @michaelsnowden Doesn't the class need to the _non-abstract_ in order for Spring to use if for its configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here

`void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse, FilterChain chain)`

Should be

`void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)`